# PHPSESSID= not carried in ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I'm trying to use $.ajax (jquery) to make an api call to my server (php). I'm successfully pinging the server, however, it's not validating that the user is logged in ( which is stored in PHPSESSID). This is a cross-domain request.

When I use PHP to make the api call from the front end, it works because the cURL request assigns the PHPSESSID to the CURLOPT_COOKIE.

Here is the **$.ajax** code on my site, www.foo.com

```
         $(document).on('click','#pickup_now', function(){

            //testing ajax function for 'cpr.php'

            $.ajax({
                url: "https://app.foo.com/CPR.php",
                data: {
                            PickupLatitude: PickupLatitude,
                            PickupLongitude: PickupLongitude,
                            PickupAddress: PickupAddress,
                            PickupAddress2: '',
                            PickupCity: PickupCity,
                            PickupState: PickupState,
                            PickupZipCode: PickupZipCode,
                            DropOffLatitude: '34.0335328',
                            DropOffLongitude: '-118.48099309999998',
                            DropOffAddress: '2227 Wilshire Boulevard',
                            DropOffAddress2: '',
                            DropOffCity: 'Santa Monica',
                            DropOffState: '5',
                            DropOffZipCode: '90403',
                            ShipmentDescription: document.getElementById('description').value,
                            ShipmentImage: document.getElementById('ShipmentImage').value,
                            EstimatedTime: '180',
                            EstimatedDistance: '1'
                        },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data,status){
                            console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
                            console.log(userSession);
                } //ends success function
            });

    });
```

It's returning:

```
Data: {"LoginValid":false}
Status: success
```

So we know it's successfully pinging the server. Here is the code on  https://app.foo.com/CPR.php

```
public static function CPR($pickupLatitude, $pickupLongitude, $pickupAddress, $pickupAddress2, $pickupCity, $pickupState, $pickupZipCode,
                                    $dropOffLatitude, $dropOffLongitude, $dropOffAddress, $dropOffAddress2, $dropOffCity, $dropOffState, $dropOffZipCode,
                                    $shipmentDescription, $shipmentImage, $estimatedTime, $estimatedDistance)
    {
        $results = new fooCommon\Results();
        if ($results->LoginValid = SessionInfo::GetInstance()->LoggedIn())
            $results->AddMembers(fooCommon\SHELPER::CPR(SessionInfo::GetInstance()->UserID(), $pickupLatitude, $pickupLongitude, $pickupAddress, $pickupAddress2, $pickupCity, $pickupState, $pickupZipCode,
                                    $dropOffLatitude, $dropOffLongitude, $dropOffAddress, $dropOffAddress2, $dropOffCity, $dropOffState, $dropOffZipCode,
                                    $shipmentDescription, $shipmentImage, $estimatedTime, $estimatedDistance));

        return $results;
    }
```

The `$results->LoginValid = SessionInfo::GetInstance()->LoggedIn()` uses the users SESSION info to validate that they are logged in and grabs their information as well.

Here is that code, found on SessionInfo.php

```
public function LoggedIn()
    {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["LoggedIn"]))
            $this->SetLoggedIn(false);

        return $_SESSION["LoggedIn"];
    }
```

How can I pass that PHPSESSID information properly so that the `SessionInfo::GetInstance()->LoggedIn()` knows to grab it and validate the user info?

**TL;DR** -> Is there a $.ajax equivalent to cURLs `CURLOPT_COOKIE`? That seems to be what's bringing that information over through the proper channel when doing this through a cURL.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: After hours (days) of scraping the world wide webiverse, I keep seeing the answer that browsers will not allow you to transfer cookies across domains. So it looks like it's a bigger problem then I thought :/

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue. You can still send cookies via PHP CURL but it seems to be blocked when using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the page renders, embed the session ID in a hidden input element, i.e.

```html
<input type=hidden name=sessionid value='<? inject here ?>'/>
```

When you make your ajax call, read the value out of the hidden input element, and include it in your data that you're posting back.

Comment: I'm able to carry over the PHPSESSID already however, it's not being properly allocated to the LoginValid function. Still getting LoginValid: false